# Rewrite rule for windows server + IIS and Cakephp 3.x

Tags: url-rewriting, cakephp-3.0

I want to deploy my site to Windows hosting from linux. On Linux server everything working as expected. but few things are not working on windows server.

Please let me know what changes i need to do in web.config

My file system is:

```
-src
-webroot
--css
--about.html
--index.php
--contact.php
```

Now how i can access about.html directly http://www.example.com/about.html and similarly for other php files too.

these are rule i am using for now:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Exclude direct access to webroot/*"
          stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^webroot/(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rewrite routed access to assets(img, css, files, js, favicon)"
          stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(assets|font|fonts|img|images|css|files|js|favicon.ico)(.*)$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="webroot/{R:1}{R:2}"
              appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rewrite requested file/folder to index.php"
          stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"
              appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```